# Handle an exception when trying to unzip a zipfile which is not present in a particular location "D:\var\logs\"

Tags: powershell, exception

I have tried using try and catch block

```
try {
$zipex=Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\aaaa\bbbbb" -DestinationPath "D:\var\log" -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] {
    Write-Verbose "Path $($_.TargetObject) not found!" -Verbose
}
```

Getting Exception
 "InvalidArgument:[Expand-Archive], InvalidOperationException
ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Expand-Archive "

Comment: that is NOT the error i get when the `-LiteralPath` points to a file that is not there.i get >>> `microsoft.powershell.archive\Expand-Archive : The path 'C:\Temp\NotThere.zip' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.` <<< are you sure the archive module is in your module path?

Comment: Looks like the "Expand-Archive" cmdlet is not found. what powershell-version do you use ? the "Expand-Archive" cmdlet is only available to Powershell5 and later

Comment: I am using the Powershell 5.1 version. I am using  "microsoft.powershell.archive" as suggested by this URL https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/52 .